# Implementing a crop image in Android

Tags: android, image, image-processing

I am trying to implement a crop image for my app.

What I want to do is that I've an `imageview` set to `300x300` .I am taking images from
`CAMERA` and `GALLERY` now the images can be bigger than `300x300`. I want to implement
a cropping tool using which I can drag the image inside imageview so that I can select the useful portion of `300x300` of the image.

I want to implement the same feature which [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snapette) app implemented for cropping.

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

https://github.com/biokys/cropimage

But if you want to  drag and fit useful portion of a image in a Imageview than you can use MultiTouch View.

https://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/

You can move the image on a custom view. Zoom and Pinch. Once you found the useful area. Take a screenshot of the imageview.

hope any of the solutions helps :)